# Object-Moving Program - Trouble Getting Stop Animation Button to Stop a Recursive Function

Tags: javascript, html

What I am really trying to accomplish is getting a shape to stop when a button is pressed. As of right now, when the user presses animate, the shape will continue to go toward the bottom right in the boundaries. I am trying to input a button that will stop the animation that is happening due to the recursive move function. I was tryin gwith the stopObj and stop functions but none of my attempts are working. If anyone knows how I should write this function to get the animations to stop it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code in question:

```
function setNewPosition(objID, dx, dy) { //This sets the new position of the     object

  var obj = getElement(objID);
  boundaryCheck(objID, dx, dy);
  var newleft = parseInt(obj.style.left) + dx;
  var newtop = parseInt(obj.style.top) + dy;
  obj.style.left = newleft.toString() + 'px';
  obj.style.top = newtop.toString() + 'px';

}

function shape(objID, canvasID, dx, dy, delay) {
  var thisShape = this;
  this.objID = objID;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
 this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;

  thisShape.draw = function() {
    drawShape(canvasID);
  }


  thisShape.move = function() {
    setNewPosition(objID, dx, dy);
    setTimeout(thisShape.move, delay);
  }
  thisShape.stop = function() {
      clearTimeout(thisShape.move);
  }
}
    function moveObj(id) { //starts process to move the shapes. 
  document.shapeObj[id].move();
}

function stopObj(id){
    document.shapeObj[id].stop();
}
```

Like I said, the trouble areas are related to the thisShape.move and thisShape.stop functions that are within the shape function. I just can't seem to get the objects to actually stop when the button is pressed.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO - When you ask a question, you should give a minimal, verifiable example. We don't know what to do with all of this code, we didn't write it. Visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: Because this assignment in particular is using all of the functions through a DOM, I need everything to replicate the issue. Would it be betteer if I just pull out the functions in question and explain whats happening through text?

Comment: I would put the specific code that's causing the issue in the post, then link to a JSFiddle with everything so that we can examine it and preform tests on the code ourselves.

Comment: I edited it down to the essential functions that are needed for this part. the stop function is the function in particular that needs work. I've never used JSFiddle, so I'll look into that now.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e45Lv21k/1/   heres a JSFiddle. It still has the line in the HTML that sources my javascript, but since its on short notice im not sure how to get it working on there without it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `clearTimeout(thisShape.move);` but `thisShape.move` is `undefined` because your function doesn't return anything.

I'm sure there's a nice way to do this with a recursive function, but it seems much easier to use `setInterval()` which is designed for this sort of thing. You can return and save the interval. Then when you want to stop, pass it to `stopInterval()` For example:

```js
const delay = 1000

function Shape() {
  this.count = 0;
  this.startMove = () => this.moveInterval = setInterval(this.move, delay);

  this.move = () => {
    console.log("moving: ", this.count)
    this.count++
  }

  this.stopMove = function() {
    console.log("stopping")
    clearInterval(this.moveInterval);
  }
}
let sh = new Shape()
sh.startMove()

function stop() {
  sh.stopMove()
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick=stop() value="stop">
```

(p.s. I converted your function declarations to arrow `=>` functions to allow using `this` in the callbacks and make the code a little clearer.)